# PDFBox 2.0.4: high memory usage when extracting images

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I manage to extract embedded images from a PDF file using PDFBOX 2.0.4 with this code:

```
        for(int i = 0; i < document.getNumberOfPages() ;i++)
        {
            PDPage page = document.getPage(i);
            PDResources resources = page.getResources();

            PDImageXObject pageImg = null;
            Iterable<COSName> xObjectNames = resources.getXObjectNames();
            for (COSName cosName : xObjectNames)
            {
                PDXObject xObject = resources.getXObject(cosName);
                if (xObject instanceof PDImageXObject) 
                {
                    PDImageXObject img = (PDImageXObject) xObject;
                    BufferedImage pageBufferedImage = pageImg.getImage();


                    targetType = pageImg.getSuffix();

                    File imageFile = new File(out, String.valueOf(i+"."+targetType));

                    ImageIO.write(pageBufferedImage,targetType,imageFile);                  
                }
            }
        }
```

The above code is working, yet the memory consumption during the extraction and the time it takes are quite problematic (the pdf files contains thousands of pages), using `BufferedImage` increases the memory usage and damages the performance, my only need is to extract the original image without any change.

I tried to use

```
pdImageXObject.getStream().toByteArray();
```

or

```
pdImageXObject.createInputStream();
```

which seems to work faster but the output file images are damaged:

[image: Example of damaged image]

Comment: The Pdfbox architecture is mostly based on an in-memory representation of the whole pdf (not completely, cf. the scratch files, but mostly). Thus, it has a substantial memory footprint. If that is a problem for you, you might want to split big files first.

Comment: Your alternative code doesn't work because these are decompressed image streams, usually 3 bytes per RGB pixel. There's nothing you can do. PDFBox 2.* has a mechanism to release the space from BufferedImage (`SoftReference` cache) but only if the memory is needed by other code.

Comment: thank you for your replay, much appreciated,  so there is no way other than using bufferImage approach ? by using bufferimage you actually pay in memory footprint and cpu utilization for the image conversions .                    i did notice the softreference usage and the memory dropped when needed, still in our case the cache is not required.    ZH.

Comment: @user1804121 If it is so important, just grab the source code and remove the few code lines that cache the BufferedImage. But the way through BufferedImage is needed unless you have your own code to handle image storing and saving. The only exception is (some) JPEG files, that are saved directly. (this is shown in the ExtractImages source code)

Comment: Tilman, what do you mean "image storing and saving", i actually prefer not to use java when it came to image manipulation, we usually use external exec (i.e http://www.graphicsmagick.org/ ) to manipulate images (much faster even by using disk IO)  Thanks again.

Comment: when i can find the source code to what you call "ExtractImages" ?

Comment: In the source code download or here: https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/tools/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/tools/ExtractImages.java?view=markup

Comment: With "image storing and saving" I mean to decompress the image, to find out what color space it is, then store it into some structure (here: BufferedImage), then to save it in some destination format (e.g. png, tiff, jpeg).

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, i will check what i can achieve using the ExtractImage (may our population contain directJPEG) and update back.

Comment: Have fun... To ping somebody (not just me), just put @ and the username. This way people get an e-mail or a sound on their mobile if they have the stackoverflow app installed.